# How to set Content-Type header on Amadeus NodeJS Package

Tags: node.js, amadeus

I am using `amadeus.client.post()` to send a request. How can I set the Content-Type header to the recommended `application/vnd.amadeus+json`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising this issue. We had a bug in our SDK, the `Content-Type` was not set correctly when using the `POST` method. This has been fixed and deployed. You can install the new version of the library: [Amadeus 3.2.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amadeus).

We updated our documentation as well to explain how to use the `amadeus.client.post`.

`amadeus.client.post('/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing', JSON.stringify({ data }));`

Comment: The header was not automatically added  when making this request for example `amadeus.client.post('/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing', {params}`. It was giving me an internal server error

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue, I updated the response above.